# Javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to convert this code to typescript :

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: {
        type: "local",
        name: "MyLocalData",
        key: "id"
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried, and what errors have you encountered?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is TypeScript so the following would work:

```
var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: {
        type: "local",
        name: "MyLocalData",
        key: "id"
    }
});
```

If it doesn't you might need to simply declare it:

```
declare var DevExpress: any; // Declare it 

var dataSource = new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
    store: {
        type: "local",
        name: "MyLocalData",
        key: "id"
    }
});
```

## More

- JavaScript is TypeScript : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/javascript/recap.html

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Basarat